# Spawing vehicle at the other side of the screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Ive got a game in which the user has to get from bottom to the top of the screen and there are vehicles moving left and right along the way. I've only included the bit of code that affects the vehicles moving left and right. 
Is there a way to get the vehicle to spawn on the far right (850) when it goes off the left of the screen (-100).

Is there a way to get the vehicle to spawn on the far right (850) when it goes off the left of the screen (-100).

I've tried changing the x_pos in several sections but it always either gets stuck on the right of the screen, stuck on the left of the screen or wont then stop when it gets to the right of the screen

```
class Vehicle(GameObject):
    #how many tiles moved per second
    speed = -5 

    def __init (self, image_path, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__ (image_path, x, y, width, height)

    def move(self, max_width):
        #makes sure that the vehicle never goes off the left of the screen
        if self.x_pos <= -100:
            self.x_pos == 850
            self.speed = -abs(self.speed)

        self.x_pos += self.speed
```

Expected that the vehicle will get to the far left and then appearing back on the far right and continuing to run from right to left.
instead it just contiunues off the left of the screen

Comment: `self.x_pos == 850` should just be `self.x_pos = 850`.

Comment: It behooves you to put the window dimensions into globals and use those instead of numbers.  Imagine you've coded up hundreds, maybe thousands of lines of program, with `850` spread all over the place in various functions and calculations.  Now you need to change the window size for the Android port! OMG!   If *only* you had defined something like `WIDTH=850` and `HEIGHT=660` variables, and used these variables throughout your program instead of some crazy number!  (Note: comment written with intention of humour, not malice).

Comment: Pygasm ive done that and it still doesnt work for some reason. just goes off the left of the screen and never reappears

Comment: Kingsley ive added a width variable in other sections of the code. i just havent included it here as there is quite alot of lines of code and didnt want to clog up the post with needless code. :)

Comment: ive got it sorted now thank you. anyone who is interested the ```self.speed = abs(self.speed)``` needed to be removed

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. You have used the comparison (`==`) operator instead of the assignment (`=`) operator:

<s>`self.x_pos == 850`</s>

```py
self.x_pos = 850
```